# Reference equation with Roman numerals

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, numbering, cleveref, roman-numerals

I would like to number my equations with Roman numerals. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtagform{Roman}[\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Roman{equation}}]()
\usetagform{Roman}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
1 + 1 = 2.
\end{equation}

A reference to \cref{eq1}.

\end{document}
```

The equation is labelled as (I), as it should be. But the reference comes out with a (Hindu)-Arabic numeral as: "eq. (1)".

How can I change my code, so that the reference comes out with a Roman numeral as: "eq. (I)"?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why don't you just do `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Roman{equation}}` and comment out the `\newtagform` and `\usetagform` calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `@frougon` said, it's easier to use the next code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Roman{equation}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
1 + 1 = 2.
\end{equation}

A reference to \cref{eq1}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Also, you can avoid using unnecessary packages using this one:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage]{article}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Roman{equation}}
\newcommand{\cref}[1]{eq. (\ref{#1})}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
1 + 1 = 2.
\end{equation}

A reference to \cref{eq1}.

\end{document}
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Employing `\newcommand{\cref}[1]{eq. (\ref{#1})}` instead of loading the `cleveref` package has some significant disadvantages. Among them are: your macro cannot handle multiple arguments, your macro allows line breaks after "eq.", and the output of `\cref{eq1}` is not guaranteed to be typeset in an upright font shape.